# Calculating sum of time if continuous records are having same data based on user input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data for each minute like below

[image: data sample]

In this based on perameter x (user input) value, if x = 2 then i have to return records with totalmoves 0 and continuously more than 2 min, if x value 3 then i have to return records having totalmoves 0 and continuous records more than 3 like this i want the out of all continuous records and total time in minutes (sum of continuous records)

and if x = 3 then expected result as below

```
TotalMoves   Id                               TrackedDateTime           TotalTimeInMin TimeGaps
0   03579A90-9098-4042-BF6B-A8507EF77BAC    2020-07-24 00:04:04.063     9                 4
0   A1BD60A9-9418-4068-A20C-3C83971A7CCB    2020-07-24 00:05:04.063     9                 4
0   1552E876-4DBB-418A-B4C4-BDF51E5CEB25    2020-07-24 00:06:04.063     9                 4
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC0    2020-07-24 00:07:04.063     9                 4
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC1    2020-07-24 00:20:04.063     9                 5
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC2    2020-07-24 00:21:04.063     9                 5
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC3    2020-07-24 00:22:04.063     9                 5   
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC4    2020-07-24 00:23:04.063     9                 5
0   EE04BE2F-F8AF-4A5D-93E1-215798F63EC5    2020-07-24 00:24:04.063     9                 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with numbered as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by TrackedDateTime) as rn 
    from T
), grouped as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by TrackedDateTime) - rn as grp
    from numbered where TotalMoves = 0
), counted as (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by grp) as cnt
    from grouped
)
select TotalMoves, Id, TrackedDateTime,
    count(*) over () as TotalTimeInMin, cnt as TimeGaps 
from counted where cnt >= 3
order by TrackedDateTime;
```

https://rextester.com/XVFFC25349

Comment: Thank you soo much #shawnt00, it's working like a charm